# Why isn't openMP working?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am doing some basic exercises to get the hang of parallelisation in C++ with OpenMP, and I am having trouble getting it to work. This is the code that I have written:

```
std::cout << "omp_get_max_threads(): " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;

for(int n=0; n<25; ++n){
  std::cout << n << " " << omp_get_num_threads() << " " << std::flush;
}
std::cout << std::endl;

#pragma omp for
for(int n=0; n<25; ++n){
  std::cout << n << " " << omp_get_num_threads() << " " << std::flush;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output I have been getting every time is:

```
omp_get_max_threads(): 4
0-1 1-1 2-1 3-1 4-1 5-1 6-1 7-1 8-1 9-1 10-1 11-1 12-1 13-1 14-1 15-1 16-1 17-1 18-1 19-1 20-1 21-1 22-1 23-1 24-1 
0-1 1-1 2-1 3-1 4-1 5-1 6-1 7-1 8-1 9-1 10-1 11-1 12-1 13-1 14-1 15-1 16-1 17-1 18-1 19-1 20-1 21-1 22-1 23-1 24-1
```

The idea is to have a baseline of a non-parallel loop, and then a parallel one to compare it to. If it was working properly, I would be expecting an output that looks more like this:

```
omp_get_max_threads(): 4
0-1 1-1 2-1 3-1 4-1 5-1 6-1 7-1 8-1 9-1 10-1 11-1 12-1 13-1 14-1 15-1 16-1 17-1 18-1 19-1 20-1 21-1 22-1 23-1 24-1 
17-4 11-4 4-4 3-4 8-4 0-4 23-4 24-4 1-4 2-4 21-4 12-4 20-4 9-4 7-4 19-4 5-4 22-4 15-4 10-4 16-4 13-4 14-4 6-4 18-4
```

Maybe not **SO** jumbled up, but at least not exactly sequential, and using more than one thread.

I am compiling using the `-fopenmp` tag. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `#pragma omp for` to `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly! if you make it an answer i can accept it if you like..

Answer (score 0):

As per High Performance Mark's comment, this is the answer, in case anyone else had a similar problem.

I used `#pragma omp parallel for` instead of just `#pragma omp parallel` and it worked perfectly